# How to select specific date with Date Picker In Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium WebDriver and using Java. I want to select the date range from the date picker showing in below screen.

Currently, I am able to select date picker and change month selection but unable to select date values (i.e - 12/10/2018)

Datepicker selection

[image: X]

Here the Java Code I have written:

```
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Leave")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apply Leave")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("LeaveStartDate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("day")).sendKeys("12");
    driver.findElement(By.id("LeaveEndtDate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("day")).sendKeys("12/11/2018");

}
}
```

Comment: can you provide HTML sample, from the image is hard to understand alot.

Comment: Can you inspect the box that says "Start Date" and copy the HTML here, please?

Comment: thanks guys....for helping and responded to my queries... it will worked with XPath....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for responded to my query... I **have tried with Xpath and its works for me**

Here the details:

With Below code i have been selecting Start & End date in **"Date Picker"**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("LeaveStartDate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[8]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("LeaveSEndDate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]")).click();
```

**Conclusion:** Xpath is the solution for those who are unable to execute their selenium Java code of **"Jquery Date Picker"**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate the box that says "Start Date" and sendKeys to that element, rather than to the datepicker itself.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("LeaveStartDate")).sendKeys("12/10/2018");
```

Then do the same for the End Date.

Comment: it will not worked for me however i have been tried with Xpath and it works for me...Thanks for the helping

Comment: No worries. I assumed the Start Date field had the ID that I used :) If my answer helped you, would you pls accept it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

to select date after changing month, You can create a List and store all date in list. Then get the text one by one using ".getText()" and try to compare the result date with your expected date and click on it. This way you can parameterize your script with date value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class dateTimePicker {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void dateTimePicker() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C://Chrome driver exe path");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/other-months.html");

        // click to open the date time picker calendar.
        WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker"));

        // click to open the date time picker calendar.
        dateBox.click();

        // Fill date as mm/dd/yyyy as 10/6/2019
        dateBox.sendKeys("10/6/2019");

        // Press tab to shift focus to time field
        dateBox.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

        // close the driver
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this utility...

```
public void selectDate(String date){  //Here any date you can give 
    WebElement eval=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'datepicker-days')]/table/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> alldates = eval.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement cell:alldates){
         String day=cell.getText();
            if (cell.getText().contains(date)) {           
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'datepicker-days')]/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='"+day+"']")).click();
                 break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Note: If you want to choose date from another month just navigate to that month and after this you can use this utility.